# Convergence via uniqueness of subsequential limits

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider a metric space and a sequence $\{a_n\}$ in it. Suppose that we can show that every converging subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ has the same limit. Can we conclude that the original sequence converges without assuming compactness of the space?

EDIT: Can we assume less than compactness and still get convergence, or is it that under the stated assumption, any such sequence will converge iff the space is compact?

EDIT2: My original question was not precise. Assume that we know every convergent subsequence has a limit and that there exists at least one convergent subsequence. Can we get away with compactness in showing that the whole sequence converges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need compactness.

Suppose that $\langle X,d\rangle$ is a non-compact metric space. Then either $X$ is not complete, or $X$ is not totally bounded. Suppose first that $X$ is not complete, and let $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$ that has no limit in $X$. It’s vacuously true that all convergent subsequences of $\sigma$ converge to the same limit, but $\sigma$ does not converge to any limit.

Now suppose that $X$ is not totally bounded. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for any finite $F\subseteq X$, $\{B(x,\epsilon):x\in F\}$ does not cover $X$. It’s easy recursively to construct a sequence $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$ such that $x_n\notin\bigcup_{k<n}B(x_k,\epsilon)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Clearly $\sigma$ has no Cauchy subsequence, so once again it’s vacuously true that all of the (non-existent) convergent subsequences of $\sigma$ converge to the same point, while $\sigma$ does not converge.

**Added:** Assuming that the sequence has at least one convergent subsequence does not help. We’ve seen above that if $X$ is not compact, it has a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ with no convergent subsequence. Let $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a convergent sequence with limit $y$, and form a new sequence $\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ by setting $z_{2n}=x_n$ and $z_{2n+1}=y_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Then every convergent subsequence of $\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $y$, but $\langle z_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge.

Comment: Thanks. This is good. My question was not very precise. I should have said that we also know there exists a convergent subsequence, so the statement is not vacuous. I have added another edit.

Comment: @passerby51: One still needs compactness; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can. Assume we have a sequence:

$$1,1/10, 10,1/100, 100,1/1000....$$

Then every convergent subsequence must converge to $0$. But the above sequence clearly does not converge to $0$ or anywhere. In the compact setting this cannot hold.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question.